# How to remove specify element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have a little problem with my script. I need to check some span, if i have some content in the middle of it i do nothing... but if it's empty i want to remove this span or for example change style. Now when specify span is empty script cleans all of my spans, even their are not empty. Can you help me?

html

```
<span class="insert_list_item"></span>
<span class="insert_list_item">data</span>
```

script

```
if ($('.insert_list_item').length > 0){
    $('.insert_list_item').each().remove();
}
```

Comment: `$('.insert_list_item').length > 0` tests if the element exists, not if there is text, `$('.insert_list_item').text().length > 0` will check if the element has text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$( '.insert_list_item' ).filter(function () { 
    return $.trim( $( this ).text() ) === '';
}).remove();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/RMZLm/

Note that this solution also works on SPAN elements that contain white-space   (e.g. `<span class="insert_list_item"> </span>`).

Comment: nice, thoes spans i have in list elements, now if span is empty i can remove whole li, much thx!

Answer (score 4):

Use `:empty`

```
$('.insert_list_item:empty').remove()
```

to remove all empty elements. Or

```
 $('.insert_list_item:not(:empty)').remove()
```

to remove all non-empty elements

On http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ you can see all selectors available.

Answer (score 2):

**each checking length:**

```
$('.insert_list_item').each( function(){
     var span = $(this);
     if (span.html().length === 0) {
         span.remove();
     }
});
```

or

**filter with :empty:**

```
$('.insert_list_item').filter(":empty").remove();
```

Comment: That second solution won't work. `is()` returns a Boolean value, not a jQuery object.

Comment: whoops, should be filter. Morning coffee has not kicked in.

Answer (score 1):

Use condition inside `each`. As each iterates through all the elements returned by selector.

```
$('.insert_list_item').each(function(){

  if($(this).html().length === 0)
       $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ($('.insert_list_item').text().length > 0){
    $('.insert_list_item').remove();
}
```